# Cannot call GetState right after GetQueryResult(queryString) on Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

On my Fabric Golang chaincode, I need to find a list of object, then loop and call `getState()` on other objects on the ledger. It work with `GetStateByRange()`, but not with `GetQueryResult()`. All those are from `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface`

With `GetQueryResult()` I get a "No revision tag detected" after every `getState()`

Examples:

This works!

```
func (s *SmartContract) queryAllFormations(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {

                resultsIterator, _ := APIstub.GetStateByRange("FORM_1","FORM_99")
                for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
                    var formation Formation
                    json.Unmarshal(formationAsBytes.Value, &formation)
                    formationAsBytes, _:= resultsIterator.Next()
                    // Will succeed !
                    personAsBytes, _:= APIstub.GetState(formation.PersonID)
                    [...]
                 }
                 resultsIterator.Close()
```

This will fail!

```
func (s *SmartContract) queryAllFormations(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {
            queryString := ...
            resultsIterator, _ := APIstub.GetQueryResult(queryString)
            for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
                formationAsBytes, _:= resultsIterator.Next()
                var formation Formation
                json.Unmarshal(formationAsBytes.Value, &formation)
                // WILL fail
                personAsBytes, _:= APIstub.GetState(formation.PersonID)
                [...]
            }
            resultsIterator.Close()
```

> error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected:
>   Error: GET_STATE failed: transaction ID:
>   2117b32cc69873be0e752eb644250c4156f29d9ec48d385f88d43ca1705b909d: No
>   revision tag detected
>       at /home/apa/DEV/rinku/rinku-server/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Peer.js:114:16
>       at /home/apa/DEV/rinku/rinku-server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:586:7

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: After looking in Fabric source code, it appears you can hit the error "No revision tag detected" if you attempt to GetState() on an empty string. I suspect your formation.PersonID may result in an empty string in the failing scenario. Can you add log statements at each step to see what is returned as formationAsBytes and what formation.PersonID resolves to?

Comment: @DaveEnyeart You are absolutly correct: some of my ID are empty. The error was missleading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @DaveEnYeart found out,  some of my ID are empty.